# Excel With Paste as picture repeating for a column

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried some of the codes suggested for similar macros.

I need the information in the cells in column L to be individually pasted as pictures in column M. I don't want to manually do this over and over for each of the hundreds of items.

Here is what it looks like without a loop or a repeat. Just doing the operation twice.

```
Sub pasteaspicture()


pasteaspicture Macro

    Range("L3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("M3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
    Range("L4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("M4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: @JaiKumar why did you remove the comments from the first row? It's supposed to be there

Comment: I didn't mean to. Here it is again with the comments. I just renamed it.  Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
    Range("L3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("M3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
    Range("L4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("M4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
End Sub

Comment: I don't think it was you Randy, but it's easier to just edit the question. Regarding your question: I have never used pictures.paste so I'm not sure I can make the code without the selects. But I can give you a general concept of what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should loop from row 3 to end of column L, if that is not what you want then I can edit it for you.

```
Application.screenupdating = False
With ActiveSheet
   LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For i = 3 To LastRow
    Range("L" & i).Copy
    Range("M" & i).Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
Next i

 Application.screenupdating = true
```

This code should work, but it includes a select, which is unwanted in VBA but since I have no clue how to use picture paste I used your code as a template.

Comment: This was amazing!! Wow Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick (but long) way to do it without loops.
It sets ranges and finds the last row of the Column.

You will find Excel has many ways to skin the same nut.  Hope this helps.

```
Sub CopyPic()

    Dim lTopRow As Long
    Dim lLeftColumn As Long
    Dim lRightColumn As Long
    Dim lLastRow As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lTopRow = .Range("L3").Row
        lLeftColumn = .Range("L3").Column

        lLastRow = .Range("L:L").Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        lRightColumn = lLeftColumn

        Application.Goto .Range(Cells(lTopRow, lLeftColumn), Cells(lLastRow, lRightColumn)), scroll:=False

        Selection.Copy

        lLeftColumn = .Range("M3").Column
        lRightColumn = lLeftColumn

        Application.Goto .Range(Cells(lTopRow, lLeftColumn), Cells(lLastRow, lRightColumn)), scroll:=False

        .Pictures.Paste.Select

    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for looking at this for me.  I have tried this and it is close. The problem with this is that it copies the entire range as one picture as opposed to each paste being a separate image. I need each cell from the L column to become its own image in the M column. How could I modify to make it work?